# Can't see new web site directory from within internal network

Tags: php, html, web-hosting, intranet

Client has an internal network (I think some flavour of Windows) for their intranet and email, and separate hosting for their web site (LAMP). They can see their current web site from within their network, but not the new site that I've put up in a temp directory on the same hosting. So:

```
url.com/index.html - they can see this
url.com/preExisitingDirectory/index.html - they can see this
url.com/myNewDirectory/index.php - they can NOT see this
```

url.com/myNewDirectory/index.php IS visible everywhere else. It's a Drupal-based CMS, and is working fine wherever I've tested it; on multiple computers, different ISPs, even on my iPhone over both WiFi and data. Even the client can see it on their iPhone, but not on their work computers.

I don't have access to their internal network - they have an IT service for that. So am trying to figure out what could possibly be happening here. My two thoughts:
1) they somehow hard-wired access to the original site's files and directories?
2) they have blocked access to PHP from their site. (Would they have to have a PHP server on their internal network, in order to allow PHP files on the hosting to run?)

Any thoughts anyone? I do have full access to the hosting, if it is at that end. But fully suspect it is something at their end.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be #1 - someone had hard-wired their internal network to point url.com to their old web host's IP address. So internally, they were actually seeing their old site, while everyone else was seeing the copy on the new hosting.
Their IT person reset it to point to the new hosting that I set up and now they see their current site and the new directory. Not sure that's the most elegant solution - will have to be changed every time they move hosts. (And I believe that forces them to have to use www.url.com internally, to specify the web site address vrs their internal network.)
HTH someone else.